# Use CSS Styled Content's default rendering typoscript but erase the divs around it

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

```
lib.inhalt = COA
lib.inhalt {
  10 < styles.content.get

  10.stdWrap.append < styles.content.getRight
  10.stdWrap.append {

  wrap = doNotPlaceAnyDivContainerHere-JustTheContentOfTheRightContentelementsPlease|

  }
```

Is it possible to achive this for an independent rendering intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rendering without divs but not the way you had in mind. Basically you would have to alter each of the possible content types that are defined in the `tt_content`. See Typoscript Object Browser to see how each content type is defined in the `tt_content` node.

```
lib.inhalt = COA
lib.inhalt {
  10 < styles.content.get

  10.stdWrap.append < styles.content.getRight
  10.stdWrap.append {
    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj {
      # Your modifications of tt_content go here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the answer doesn't help you get what you want, post the HTML output of the right column content that you are getting and point out which wrapping you want to remove.